# Null value parameters not hitting on Web api contoller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

This api contoller  hit only when first two  parameter is non nullable, if both datetime parameter is null,then it is not hitting ,I getting a 404 error , please give a solution

```
 [HttpGet("userReports/{empid:int}/{sdate:DateTime?}/{edate:DateTime?}")]

        public IEnumerable<object> usersReport(int empid,DateTime? sDate, DateTime? edate)
        {

            return employeeDailyStatusService.GetUserReport(empid, sDate, edate);

        }
```

I'm using this url for testing in postman

```
https://localhost:44308/api/EmployeeDailyStatus/userReports/14/null/null
```

Comment: As Sergey said, try to change the url to `https://localhost:44308/api/EmployeeDailyStatus/userReports/14`, if still not working, have you ever added the Route attribute at the top of the API controller? Try to post the related code.

Answer (score 0):

Any routing will translate you url

```
https://localhost:44308/api/EmployeeDailyStatus/userReports/14/null/null
```

as this

```
https://localhost:44308/api/EmployeeDailyStatus/userReports/14/"null"/"null"
```

null will be just a string "null".

You just need this url:

```
https://localhost:44308/api/EmployeeDailyStatus/userReports/14
```